Does 4wd in park lock front wheels?
2010 Silverado 1500 4wd
If the truck is in 4wd and the transmission is in park (truck turned off), are the front wheels locked from spinning?
In other words, if the rear wheels were jacked up off the ground, and no wheel chocks used, would the truck roll on the front tires in 4wd?

If your Silverado in Park has a manual transfer case in 4WD Hi or Lo without a locking rear differential, raising any one wheel off the ground will allow all wheels to roll without resistance just as if the truck were in Neutral. Just leaning on the truck could make it roll.
If your Silverado in Park has an automatic limited slip transfer case in Auto or 4WD Hi or Lo, OR if you have a locking rear differential, raising one wheel off the ground will allow all wheels to roll with some resistance. So leaning on the truck would probably not make it roll, but parking on an incline could cause it to roll.
In other words, no matter how the truck is equipped, Park is not a substitute for chocks if any wheel is off the ground.
